# ImportError: No module named 'theano'

Tags: python, theano

I have installed (/library/python/2.7/site-packages) theano on my mac and still get this error.

**My code is**

```
import theano
theano.test()
```

**and the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Downloads/n.py", line 1, in <module>
    import theano
ImportError: No module named 'theano'
```

I did install theano using pip install theano for python 2.7.

Any idea on why its throwing up the error.

Also I installed Anaconda and it throws the same error as working on idle.

Comment: Which directory did the module install into?

Comment: /library/python/2.7/site-packages

Comment: Is that the only module in that directory?  There are several ways around this.  You can add that directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (usually in your `.bash_profile` or similar) or in the program you can append the directory name to `sys.path`.

Comment: theano is in that directory. you want a path in to theano in echo $path?

Comment: Any chance you are running Python 3 when testing? How are you running your test code (relying on `#!` to load Python, or running `python n.py`)? What does `python --version` say?

Comment: Running from terminal so its taking python -V
Python 2.7.12

Comment: Added numpy and theano to the path and it still throws up the no module for both numpy and theano

Comment: What does `print sys.path` say? Does it have site-packages?

Comment: you mean echo $PATH? yes it has all the packages

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem trying to install pygame, i'm using python 3.4.1 so I'm not 100% sure this will work for you

Here is my folder: C:\Python34\Scripts[image]

**The problem:**
This will of course be different for you, but this is what I did anyway:
I did `pip install pygame` and it seemed to work but when I tried `import pygame` I got the same error as you

**My solution:** 
instead of installing pygame with pip, I did `pip3 install pygame` and it worked! so for you, look at what files you have in this folder **/library/python/2.7/site-packages** and try all of them, try `pip2 install theano`, try `pip2.7 install theano`, try `pip3 install theano`, try everything!

Again I'm not certain this will work for python 2.7, but its worth a try :)

Comment: tried pip2.7 install numpy and scipy, it says already installed.  Then tried pip3.6 installed numpy,theano and scipy and on compiling it says unable to import theano.. There is numpy & scipy installed in 2.7 but on compile it says "no module found". The path has been changed to to the respective directories.  I am out of tricks now :/

Comment: it works with me when i used: pip3 install theano , I'm suign python 3.5

Answer (score 3):

```
On windows 7, Python 3.6.0 - Anaconda 4.3.1 (64bits)
```

```
>pip install theano   ¡thanks!
```

[Used command view image clic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3fuM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,
my problem was i messed up (i am very new with python) with python bins,
so i had 3 versions :
-- os level
-- anaconda
-- anaconda with virtual env

as being not aware some packegs/updates i was doing on one of above options, and  theano was not working, finally realized all this mees i have created, and using virtual env version is wrokign for me

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem, i fixed it with uninstalling all versions of Python (which were overshadowing each other), and then installing latest version 'Windows x86-64 executable installer' from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Comment: I installed anaconda and use the anaconda prompt.  Also use spyder

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem too,I tried serval methods,but not work.
Last,this commond help me.
you can try:

> pip install -r
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/v0.1/requirements.txt
>
> pip install -r
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/master/requirements.txt
>
> pip install https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
>
> pip install -r
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dnouri/kfkd-tutorial/master/requirements.txt